# IntellliJ IDEA LightEdit mode won't open file if IDE already running

Tags: intellij-idea

When I use the `idea` command line tool to open a file in LightEdit mode

```
$ idea myfile.txt
```

and IDEA is already open in project mode it will not open file file. IDEA gets focus but the file does not open.

However, when I used the `idea` command line to open a file in LightEdit mode and IDEA is not already open, it works as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use the `Create Command-line launcher` option to recreate the idea launcher file it will start working as expected.